# Android: Why does MapView complain about LOGIN ACCOUNTS MISSING when running in emulator?

Tags: android

I am trying to get a MapView to display on the emulator. When I look at logcat, this is the error message I am receiving. I have no idea why?

Device has no accounts: sending Intent { act=com.google.android.gsf.LOGIN ACCOUNTS MISSING }

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it is not possible to run Google Android Maps v2 on an emulator. Check out the comments on [this](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Tyz491d96Ci) post by Android Developers. Also, look at the official [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) to the play services

`Note: Google Play services is not supported on the Android emulator — to develop using the APIs, you need to provide a development device such as an Android phone or tablet.`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. Pls. make sure that you have the maps key. Also make sure you have the required permissions on the manifest. For more you could refer to : https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Tyz491d96Ci